# Content Moderation: Remove transition from select list programmatically

Tags: 8, hooks

How do I alter this select list programmatically in my module?

[image: Remove Request publish for this role programmatically]

Permissions won't work here since all the roles can use the 'Request publish' transition, but the roles that can also use the 'Published' transition don't need to see 'Request publish'. I think the easiest way to make this change is to remove 'Request publish' from the dropdown list.

I'm working with [hook_field_widget_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_widget_form_alter/8.5.x.)

The code that I'm trying to override is from formElement() in ModerationStateWidget.php.

Thanks.

Comment: I think `hook_form_alter()` will do.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @No Sssweat. You put me on the right track.

Since this is the node form, I opted to use [hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter/8.5.x).

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter() for node_form().
 */
function MY_MODULE_form_node_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $roles = \Drupal::currentUser()->getRoles();
  if (array_intersect(['role_1', 'role_2', 'role_3'], $roles)) {
    $options = isset($form['moderation_state']['widget']) ? $form['moderation_state']['widget'][0]['state']['#options'] : [];
    $options = array_diff_key($options, [
      'request_publish' => 'Request Publish',
      'request_unpublish' => 'Request unpublish',
      'request_delete' => 'Request Delete'
    ]);
    $form['moderation_state']['widget'][0]['state']['#options'] = $options;
  }
}
```